# In the Atom editor, in a sass or scss file, how to see the resulting selector that I'm editing?

Tags: sass, atom-editor

In RubyMine, when editing SASS or SCSS, the "compiled" path to the selector for the code you're currently editing is shown. Is there a way to do the same in the Atom editor? A tooltip or a status bar is what I'm looking for. In big SASS/SCSS files, it can be 100s of lines to the outer-most selector, and it is way too easy to insert a new selector at the wrong spot.

Answer (score 1):

A package that claims to do what you want is [`ctags-status`](https://atom.io/packages/ctags-status):

> ## ctags-status package
>
> Show the class/function/scope name of the current line on the status bar.
>
> [image: ctags-status demo GIF]
>
> ...
>
> ### Tested languages
>
> - C / C++
> - Coffeescript
> - CSS / LESS / SCSS / SASS
> - ...

However, I installed it, and it only worked for the first level of Sass/SCSS selectors; it only displayed `[a]`, or `[.container]` instead of something like `[.container > a]`. It also only re-evaluates your position after a save.

Comment: I'll give it a go. Thank you. I don't mind if it takes a save to re-calculate, but my hope is to have it calculate the entire selector, because I can almost always see the local one.

Comment: You're quite right: it only shows the immediate "ancestor" in the SCSS hierarchy, not the full path to the root. It doesn't look like it would handle compound ancestors correctly either:

```.this, .that { .the { .other { color: red; } } }```

should evaluate to ```.this .the .other, .that .the .other```, but I don't see anything about ctags-status that could handle it. Thanks, though!

Comment: @DaveLand Yeah, sorry I couldn't help you more!

Comment: Nonetheless, you answered and I was given the opportunity to give it a try, so I'm happy to give you an updoot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to tick the "Show outer scope(s)" checkbox in the settings of the ctags-status package in order for the full path to the root to be displayed. Works like a charm here.